# zend2 mysql - joining table using TableGateway

Tags: zend-framework2

I want to aquire data from two mySql tables:

```
SELECT L.id AS 'l_id', L.date, L.action, U.id AS 'u_id', U.name, U.surname 
FROM cases_log L, users U 
WHERE L.user = U.id 
LIMIT 0,30
```

So, I've decided to use $select->join, but it doesn't work in way I want. It has aqured data only from cases_log table.

```
SELECT * 
FROM `cases_log` 
JOIN users 
ON users.id = cases_log.user
```

Module.php:

```
'HistoryTable' =>  function($sm) 
{
    $tableGateway = $sm->get('HistoryTableGateway');
    $table = new HistoryTable($tableGateway);
    return $table;
},
'HistoryTableGateway' => function ($sm) 
{
    $dbAdapter = $sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
    $resultSetPrototype = new ResultSet();
    $resultSetPrototype->setArrayObjectPrototype(new History());
    return new TableGateway('cases_log', $dbAdapter, null, $resultSetPrototype);
},
```

HistoryTable.php:

```
$table = $this->tableGateway;
$select = $table->getSql()->select();
//$select->from(array('L' => 'cases_log'))->join(array('U' => 'users'),'L.user = U.id');
$select->join('users', 'users.id = cases_log.user');

$select->limit(10);
$select->offset(0);         
$resultSet = $table->selectWith($select);

return $resultSet;
```

As You can see, in commented line, I've tried to do something in $select->from - but without result, because $select->from is read only ...

I'm new to ZF2 so, I miss somethis maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$table = $this->tableGateway;
$select = $table->getSql()->select();
$select->columns(['l_id' => 'id', 'date', 'action']);
$select->join('users', 'users.id = cases_log.user', ['u_id' => 'id', 'name', 'surname']);
$select->limit(10);
$select->offset(0);
```

produces the correct sql (except the aliases for the table)

Comment: it works ! But whai if I want to add another table to query ? in example : "SELECT L.date, L.action, U.name, U.surname, U.wpis, U.ppis, C.id AS 'caseId', C.nazwa_firmy FROM cases_log L, users U, cases C WHERE (L.user = U.id AND L.caseId=C.id) ORDER BY L.date DESC LIMIT 0,10"

Comment: Then simply add it as a join: `$select->join('cases', 'cases.id = cases_log.caseId', ['caseId' => 'id', 'nazwa_firmy']);`

Comment: hmm... but I've found problem. I have to add caseId and nazwa_firmy vars to History(). If I do that I will can't use History() to insert data to database because of this two vars.